# Are below sentences held in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

$(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to r) \lor (q \to r))$

$(p \to (q \lor r)) \to ((p \to q) \lor (p \to r))$

are holded in intuitionistic logics?

I could not found the model of intuitional logic that aboves are not true.

So, if these can be proved, give me a proof of it. Unless, I wanna get the inconsistent model of intuitionistic logics with those two sentences.

Comment: Can you prove these in non-intuitionistic logic?  What goes wrong in the proof?

Comment: What sorts of models have you tried?

Comment: I made a model that truth-values are 0(=truth), 1(=weak false), 2(=strong false), and i -> j matches 0 when i>=j and j when i<j. this model was not satisfied peirce's law but satisfied above two sentences.

Comment: I modified the notation. please double check.

Comment: It would surprise me if this isn't a duplicate question - especially for the second one, I'm pretty sure I remember seeing that one here previously.  Pretty much the canonical counterexamples I'm aware of would be: for the first, use the Kripke frame where $\mathbb{P} = \{ \{\}, \{ p \}, \{ q \}, \{ p, q, r \} \}$; for the second, use the Kripke frame where $\mathbb{P} = \{ \{\}, \{ p, q \}, \{ p, r \} \}$.

Comment: Also, in the first one if you substitute $r := \bot$, then it is equivalent to $(\lnot(p\land q)) \rightarrow ((\lnot p) \lor (\lnot q))$ which is the implication from de Morgan's laws which "famously" does not hold intuitionistically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

The first claim is not even true classically. Can you find a way to falsify it in a very simple boolean algebra? (For instance, one with $4$ elements?)

The second claim *is* true classically (replace $a \to b$ by $\lnot a \lor b$ everywhere to see why), but is *not* true intuitionistically. To see why, you'll want a heyting algebra which falsifies it. And it's not worth looking at boolean ones, since we know the claim is true classically.

Since you have $3$ primitive propositions ($p$, $q$, and $r$), you might try to find a model where $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all incomparable. I'll tell you that there's a heyting algebra with $9$ elements that does the trick. Can you take it from here?

**Edit:**

After your edit, the first claim *is* true classically (as you've noted), but is still false intuitionistically. To see why, consider the same $9$ element heyting algebra that I alluded to for your second proposition. Again, you should put $p$, $q$, and $r$ along the middle row of this lattice. Can you compute $q \to r$, $p \to q \to r$, etc. and see that this falsifies the claim?

As a bonus hint, while you put $p$, $q$, and $r$ in the middle both times, you'll have to put them in different positions for proposition $1$ and $2$. Thankfully there's only $3$ permutations to try, so it shouldn't take you long to check them all.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: the notation was confusable. I modifed it. Sorry sir. I already know that above sentences are classically true. but I don't know that those are "intuitionistic" true. that is, disjuction is defined by "Proof by Case".

Comment: @Paul -- I've edited my answer to fit with your updated question. Also, I'm not a "sir".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found them and those are equivalent to ((p->q) or (q->p)).

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain their issue with this answer?